# select max date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have table where it contains order_id, status and update_date. status may be success or failure. Each order can have these status multiple times with different update date except 'success' status like below.

```
order_id status  update_date
1001    failure 01-01-2015
1001    failure 02-01-2015
1001    success 03-01-2015
1001    failure 04-01-2015
1002    failure 02-01-2015
1002    failure 03-01-2015
```

I need to select each order id with latest update date with their respective status and in case if the order has success status, then its respective update date like below

```
1001 success 03-01-2015
1002 failure 03-01-2015
```

pls help to get this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT order_id,
  status,
  update_date
FROM(SELECT order_id,
            status,
            update_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY order_id order by DECODE(status,'success',1,0) DESC,update_date DESC) rn
      FROM test1)
WHERE rn=1;
```

P.S : test1 is my table name with your data.